# Can not receive input from azure stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I try to read EventHub data from stream analytics. but not i got "Data not found error"
connection is established and triggering the events were success. what to do?
[When I run the query, i get below message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvcUy.png)

Comment: Can you please make sure there're events in EventHub? and please also check other settings like time range you specified?

Answer (score 0):

As Ivan comments,please make sure there're events in EventHub,and then follow this:

1.add inputs from your Event Hub.
[image]

2.select your Event Hub name.

[image]

3.write a SQL to query
[image]

More details,you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-manage-job).